# Copying files from Linux server to windows machine over SSH, using expect script and crontab is not reliable

Tags: linux, ssh, pdf, cron, scp

We have a server that is producing reports from some elements in two formats. PDF and DOCX. I created a crontab job to automate transfer of these files from the server to one of the local Windows workstations.

I installed SSH server on Windows machine and I created a expect script, because there is a password on a windows user and a simple SCP script did not work. I found a solution online (using expect script). This arrangement sort of works. Except that it does not work all of the time, and when it does, it happens that the script only copies PDF files or it only copies DOCX files, or it does not copy both files from some element.

I don’t know where to start debugging such issue.

The funny thing is that if I run the SCP command (from the script), in the terminal, it copies everything.

```
scp -r -p /home/kns_ftp/MPS_report/ mnadmin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:C:/Users/mnadmin/desktop/
```

p.s. I have changed some values in "xxx" just because of basic security hygiene.

SCRIPT LOCATION IN ROOT HOME (kopiranje_batt.exp):

```
\[root@kns-db \~\]# ll

\-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   196 Jan 13  2023 kopiranje_batt.exp
```

EXPECT SCRIPT:

```
\[root@kns-db \~\]# cat kopiranje_batt.exp
#!/usr/bin/kopiranje_batt

spawn scp -r -p /home/kns_ftp/MPS_report/ mnadmin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:C:/Users/mnadmin/desktop/
set pass "xxx"
expect {
password: {send "$pass\\r"; exp_continue}
}
```

CRONTAB:

```
\[root@kns-db \~\]# crontab -l
0 05,09,10,18,20,22 \* \* \* expect /root/kopiranje_batt.exp
```

EXAMPLE FROM WINDOWS WINSCP:

As you can see from image, from some elements only DOCX was copied, from others only PDF

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2I8T.jpg)

Comment: When using ssh and avoiding interactivity, use what ssh provides: authentication keys instead of passwords. (Not so) random search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement#deploying-the-public-key